# SET $per_page from input type text in codeingiter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

hello guys i have the following problem: i've set up my pagination with the help of codeigniter pagination class but i want to do something more:

I would like users to enter a value in an input box... and then the `$per_page` to be set automaticaly at that value:

here is my code:

```
public function index($offset = NULL, $limit = NULL)
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $total = $this->db->count_all('posts');

        $per_page = 5;      

        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'welcome/index';
        $config['total_rows'] = $total;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['per_page'] = $per_page;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['posts'] = $this->Model_cats->get_pagination_field($config['per_page'], $offset);
```

and so on...

the pagination work great!

this is the html:

```
<div id="pagination">

    <?php  echo $pagination;?> 
    <input type="text" id="set_pagination">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_pagination">

</div>
```

ok how can i submit a number let's say 3 and show me **3 posts per page**?

Any idea?   `$per_page = $this->input->post`.... something..

Answer (score 1):

follow the steps.

```
1) save the text box value in DB.

2) In DB there will be a single row containing value of per_page. all time this value will be updated.

3) when you are using pagination class pick up that value from DB.
```

Hope this will work for you. any better idea than this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to achieve this to post the value to the function,

```
<div id="pagination">
   <?php echo form_open("controller/function"); ?>
    <?php  echo $pagination;?> 
    <input type="text" id="set_pagination" name="set_pagination">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_pagination">
   <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

In your controller function, get the value.

```
$per_page = $this->input->post('set_pagination');
```

Then store the value in DB (or) Session.

Comment: i've added <input type="text" name="set_pagination" value="<?php echo set_value("set_pagination"); ?>">   to the input so that my value is saved! because when i click to go on the second page it doesn't save me the value... and this function saves me the value just on the first page... any idea?

Comment: @PaulHarbuz Use Session or store the value in DB. Then refer in all pages

Answer (score 0):

First change your per_page as

```
$per_page = 3;
```

and to your model send $per_page including with offset as

```
$data['posts'] = $this->Model_cats->get_pagination_field($config['per_page'], $offset,$per_page);
```

and at your model write limit as

```
$this->db->limit($perpage,$offset);
```

thats it....hope it help for you